# How to declare custom object eg. Timer in codable class

Tags: ios, json, swift, codable

I'm facing an issue with codable. I'm not able to understand how to init custom timer object in codable class.

```
    class ShelfItem: Codable {

      var objTimer = Timer()
```

or i try to do it like

```
     // var objTimer: Timer()
    }
```

but it show me the error that is "Type 'ShelfItem' does not conform to protocol 'Encodable'"

Comment: The `var objTimer = Timer()` doesn’t make sense (a timer with no handler and no specified time to fire). And `var objTimer: Timer()` is just syntactically incorrect. But let’s set that aside and ask what you’re expecting to be encoded: As vadian said, it doesn’t make sense to encode/decode a `Timer`, itself, so you’d either exclude it from coding or take the unusual step to encode/decode enough so the timer could be reconstituted later (which is a strange notion with timers). Perhaps you can describe why you’re trying to encode/decode a timer and describe what you’re hoping to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

It makes no sense to en-/decode a `Timer` object.

To exclude `objTimer` from encoding add `CodingKeys` for the other properties and omit `objTimer`.

Simple example (in most cases you don't even need a class)

```
struct ShelfItem : Codable {
    let name : String
    var timer : Timer

    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey { case name }

    init(from decoder : Decoder) throws
    {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        name = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
        timer = Timer()
    }
}
```

Comment: i want to add custom object in Model so that's why i add Timer in codable.

Comment: Yes, but you don't need to encode the `Timer` instance. Create it in the initializer when decoding the JSON/Property List.

Comment: Can you write sudo code or code here which you're saying. How to initialize Timer and add it in codable class object.

Comment: what is the name and why i need it?

Comment: i receiving nil object when i parse in codable class.

Comment: `name` is an assumption. I have no idea what your class contains. If you want a concrete solution post sufficient information.

Comment: class ShelfItem: Codable {
    
    let name: String
    var objTimer : Timer
    var prepProductID: Int?
    var productName: String?
    var expireTime: String?
}

I'm facing error on objTimer. i try to initialize it as you mentioned but failed. I don't need coding keys for all of these variables.

Comment: What error? As I said you **do** need CodingKeys for **all** properties which are going to be decoded.

Comment: error as i mentioned in my question. Brother i don't need coding keys for all. i just want to add timer object in my response. Because i want add timer for every object.